# tokenizing with regular expression python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, tokenize

I  have the following code which  I want to tokenize a text  located in my directory with regular expression

```
def tokenize():
    infile = codecs.open('test_test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    text = infile.read()
    infile.close()
    words = []
    with io.open('test_test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        text = unicode_csv_reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        for item in text:
            for word in item:
                words.append(word)
                tregex = re.compile(ur'[?&/\'\r\n]', re.IGNORECASE)
                newtext1 = tregex.sub(' ', text)
                newtext = re.sub(' +', ' ', newtext1)
                words = re.split(r' ', newtext)
                print words
```

but i get  this error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\KKSC\KKSC.py", line 150, in OnCheckSpell
tokenize()
File "D:\KKSC\KKSC.py", line 32, in tokenize
newtext1 = tregex.sub(' ', text)
```

TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: It looks like you're assigning _words_ twice, is that correct?

Comment: if you mean that line for  [Print words ] its only for the testing if i get the result of the tokenized text. but so far I couldn't  get it because of the error .
but when i comment 
         #   tregex = re.compile(ur'[?&/\'\r\n]', re.IGNORECASE)
         #   newtext1 = tregex.sub(' ', text)
        # newtext = re.sub(' +', ' ', newtext1) 
I get the same  content  of the text that I need to tokenize it with out any change (  to be tokenized ).

Answer (score 0):

```
newtext1 = tregex.sub(' ', text)
```

`text` is a 2 dimensional array of strings, while `sub` expects a string. Do you mean:

```
newtext1 = tregex.sub(' ', word) ?
```

Comment: yes ..  is it correct if i change  newtext1 = tregex.sub(' ', text) to newtext1 = tregex.sub(' ', word) ?

Comment: Dear @cristiFati  i have another issue on it ,, can i have your help on it ??

Comment: yes, i'll try to do my best...if you let me know what the problem is.

Comment: I have already started with python, currently I working on building a spell checker for non ASCII Language( Unicode)using python. i have used simple wxpython text editor below are the source codes:

Comment: can i have your email , so that i can show you my problem if it's possible dear @CristiFati ?

Comment: fati_utcluj@yahoo.com

Comment: I have sent you an email dear @CristiFati